# Adding element to multiple array with single command in Perl

Tags: perl

Can I add element to more than 1 array using push in perl?

E.g.

```
my @arr1 = qw/one two three/;
my @arr2 = qw/four five six/;
push (@arr1,@arr2), "extra";
```

Expected Output ::

```
@arr1 = one two three extra
@arr2 = four five six extra
```

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation for `push()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html) is pretty clear.

> **push ARRAY,LIST**
>
> Treats ARRAY as a stack by appending the values of
>   LIST to the end of ARRAY. The length of ARRAY increases by the length
>   of LIST. Has the same effect as
>
> ```
> for my $value (LIST) {
>     $ARRAY[++$#ARRAY] = $value;
> }
> ```
>
> but is more efficient. Returns the number of elements in the array following the completed push.
>
> Starting with Perl 5.14, an experimental feature allowed push to take
>   a scalar expression. This experiment has been deemed unsuccessful, and
>   was removed as of Perl 5.24.

So, no. `push()` only works with a single array at a time.

Your solution:

```
push (@arr1,@arr2), "extra";
```

Would have the effect of adding all of `@arr2`'s elements to the end of `@arr1`. The "extra" would be ignored as the closing parenthesis would be seen as ending the list of parameters to `push()`. Under `use warnings` you would get a warnings saying:

> Useless use of a constant ("extra") in void context

You could do this by using two calls to `push()` and hiding the complexity in a subroutine. The naive solution uses references to the arrays:

```
sub twopush {
  my ($a1, $a2, @elems) = @_;

  push @$a1, @elems;
  push @$a2, @elems;
}

twopush(\@arr1, \@arr2, "extra");
```

But this is one of those rare occasions where Perl's subroutine prototypes come in useful. You can tell the subroutine that the first two parameters are arrays and the compiler will handle taking the references.

```
sub twopush(\@\@@) {
  my ($a1, $a2, @elems) = @_;

  push @$a1, @elems;
  push @$a2, @elems;
}

twopush(@arr1, @arr2, "extra");
```

Comment: Or just use a loop: `push @$_, "extra" for \@arr1, \@arr2;`